# Translate a selection of string in array using a datatable field from VB.net code to c#

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, datatable

I am translating some VB.Net code to C# but I cannot figure out how to do this If statement in VB.Net:

```
If auxstr(dt.Rows(i).Item("Fieldname")) = "---" Or auxstr(dtn.Rows(i).Item("Fieldname")) = "--" Then
```

where 'auxstr' is an array of string and 'dt' a DataTable previously taken from the DB

Perhaps with linQ but I am not very familiar with it, any ideas?
****edit****
no need for linQ here, Value of the table's field was an index , statement was just comparing the string value of that certain position in the array

Thanks!

Comment: Have you even tried? SO is not a code conversion service

Comment: are `dt` and `dtn` arrays or dictionaries?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: He says 'dt' is a DataTable - I assume 'dtn' is also.

Comment: Well found out the field's value in the table was an index, so it was more a misunderstanding of the program itself, convert the value of the table to integer is enough, thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Item' indexer methods in VB convert to C# indexers and the string array needs to be indexed by an integer, not object (you should use Option Strict On in your VB code), so you would have:

```
if (auxstr[Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Fieldname"])] == "---" || auxstr[Convert.ToInt32(dtn.Rows[i]["Fieldname"])] == "--")
{
}
```

Comment: this is correct. It is a bit strange how the index of an array is equal to/stored in a column of a dt, but that has nothing to do with the answer provided, would need more context to understand it.

Comment: @RicardoOlivoPoletti: I've seen much stranger things with Option Strict Off.

Answer (score 1):

building on Dave Doknjas answer, don't do th emost complex part of this twice.

```
var inx = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Fieldname"]);

if (auxstr[inx] == "---" || auxstr[inx] == "--")
{
}
```

Comment: It's not twice - one uses 'dt' and one uses 'dtn'.

Comment: Good point, but that may be a typo by the OP.  He only mentions `dt` in the text, and the things it's compared against are different.